# PCI DSS requirement 8.3.1

Tags: pci-dss

I have a question regarding this requirement, does even the non-CHD system need to use 2FA?

Ex: When accessing CHD server it asks for 2FA, but do we need the system that accessing from to have 2FA as well?

Comment: The PCI document appears not to care about the *system* but the *environment*.

Comment: Does that means the environment that non CHD should have the 2FA.

Note that the environment that non CHD access the environment that have CHD.

Comment: you are asking a 'scope' question - once you identify the scope, then 8.3.1 applies to all *systems* in scope, even if they do not have card holder data

Answer (score 1):

The first problem I seem to encounter revolves around the difference between systems/devices that process/store/transmit cardholder data (aka Category 1 systems/devices) versus those systems/devices that are connected to those Category 1 systems/devices (aka Category 2 systems/devices).  The guidance here is that if a Category 2 system has the ability to effect the security of a Category 1 system (i.e., the Category 2 system/device has inbound access to the CDE system(s)/device(s)), then administrators should also use MFA to access those Category 2 systems/devices.

Curled from https://pciguru.wordpress.com/2017/01/07/getting-ready-for-8-3-1/Chris